# How to upgrade log4j-api tp 2.17 in Jfrog Artifactory?

Tags: log4j, artifactory

Jfrog recommends to upgrade log4j to 2.15 as permanent fix. Can I just replace with the latest log4j-api.jar file? or Does Jfrog release latest patch for this?

How can I completely fix the issue?
The best fix for this issue would be to upgrade your log4j dependencies to version 2.15.0, which resolved the issue in several layers and improved the overall security of log4j.

As an additional layer of protection, we also recommend setting the LOG4J_FORMAT_MSG_NO_LOOKUPS environment variable globally (see next section).

Answer (score 2):

@Syed JFrog products are not affected by this vulnerability, as they are not using the log4j-core package. We can confirm that JFrog services are not affected by CVE-2021-44228.

JFrog Security has validated that JFrog Platform solutions themselves are not affected, as no products, including Artifactory version 6.x or 7.x using the log4j-core package. CVE-2021-44228 only affects ‘log4j-core’, which is not being used in Artifactory. Other packages such as log4j-over-slf4j, log4j-api and log4j-to-slf4j are unaffected.

Hence, there is no action required from users to upgrade this library.

Comment: I am aware of this but my org wants every one to update log4j version to 2.17 irrespective if its effected or now. So my question is can I just replace the log4j-api-2.11.jar to latest 2.17 directly and restart the service?